# ZoneAvoidanceRule choose method invoked twice before actual request is fired causing issues to round robin

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix

I am using Ribbon indirectly through `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate` in my application built on top of Spring Cloud Netflix.

I am testing the round-robin load balancing (which should be part of the default `ZoneAvoidanceRule` defined by Spring) against two target servers. However this is not working.

What I noticed when debugging the application is that the `loadBalancer` is asked twice to `choose` the destination server based on the rule and the available server list.

The first time the request to choose the destination server is done because of the `RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(URI, HttpMethod)` method. The second time is the effect of invoking the `execute` method on the `loadBalancer` itself which will in turn choose again the destination target. As a result, (having only two available servers) I keep on hitting only one.

Do I have something mis-configured or is this a bug?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 1.0.1.RELEASE (spring-cloud-netflix-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.0.2.RELEASE has fixed this issue.